# Firebase .getvalue not in the same order as database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database is like this

[image: Firebase Database]

When the coding below was run:

```
String loc=(snapshot.child("loc").getvalue()).tostring();
```

The output I get has different sequence with the database:

[image: Output]

Why is that so?

Comment: Is the ordering important?

Comment: Yes, the ordering is important.

Comment: can you show the firebasse database ref , i think you firebase ref is pointing to wrong node

Comment: @jwen Then why are you not using `child("loc").orderByKey()`?

Comment: @cricket_007 my bad, it is done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase data is stored as JSON and is inherently unordered.

If you want to access the data in a specific order, you should specify an `orderBy` clause for your query and access the data using the snapshot's `getChildren()` method.

Say you want to log the items by ascending key:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRef();
Query locations = rootRef.orderByKey();
locations.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot locSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(locSnapshot.getKey() + ": " + locSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    }
  }

  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
  }
});
```

This sample comes (modified) from the [Firebase documentation on reading lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Answer (score 1):

Frank beat me to my edit, check out his correct solution using `orderBy....`

---

You need to use `forEach` rather than the `child` method (or  `child.foreach`)

Here is a snippet from the doc:

> Because of the way JavaScript Objects work, the ordering of data in
>   the JavaScript Object returned by val() is not guaranteed to match the
>   ordering on the server nor the ordering of child_added events. That is
>   where forEach() comes in handy. It guarantees the children of a
>   DataSnapshot will be iterated in their query-order.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach

Comment: This is a Java question. Why are you quoting the JavaScript library?

Comment: I meant more that `forEach` is not a method of the Java API

Comment: Right you are, let me fix that.